# How do I keep XmlDocument.Save from writing namespaces of new elements?

Tags: xml, powershell

I've written a PowerShell script that looks into an XML and uncomments some items.
The way I do this is by removing the comment and creating new `XmlElement` objects to take it's place.

My problem is when I save the file over the existing one, `XmlDocument` adds an extra attribute my root elements `xmlns=""` .
I used my debugger to look at the `XmlDocument` object before saving and my new element's `OuterXml` has the following structure:

```
  <register type="IComStack" mapTo="ComStackEth">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
    <constructor>
      <param name="host" type="System.Net.IPAddress">
        <value value="127.0.0.1" typeConverter="IPAddressTypeConverter" />
      </param>
    </constructor>
  </register>
```

After saving I look in the file and my element looks like this:

```
  <register type="IComStack" mapTo="ComStackEth" xmlns="">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
    <constructor>
      <param name="host" type="System.Net.IPAddress">
        <value value="127.0.0.1" typeConverter="IPAddressTypeConverter" />
      </param>
    </constructor>
  </register>
```

I then go back to the debugger and look at my element again and I see it in the correct format i.e. without the xmlns attribute.

I use `$config.Save($configPath)` top save my xml and I load it using:

```
$config= new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$config.Load($configPath)
```

Does anyone know how I can prevent `XmlDocument.Save` from adding the namespace attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know how I can prevent `XmlDocument.Save` from adding the namespace attribute?

By creating the elements in the correct namespace.

In isolation, the XML document

```
  <register type="IComStack" mapTo="ComStackEth">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
    <constructor>
      <param name="host" type="System.Net.IPAddress">
        <value value="127.0.0.1" typeConverter="IPAddressTypeConverter" />
      </param>
    </constructor>
  </register>
```

contains a number of elements with various local names and *no* namespace.  And the XML document

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
  <!-- content goes here -->
</root>
```

contains an element named `root` in the `http://example.com` namespace.  If you want to add child nodes to this `root` element and those nodes are not in the `http://example.com` namespace then the serializer *must* add suitable namespace declarations - if it did not add `xmlns=""` then the result would not be correct because the elements that were previously in no namespace would "move" into the `http://example.com` namespace.

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
  <register type="IComStack" mapTo="ComStackEth" xmlns="">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
    <constructor>
      <param name="host" type="System.Net.IPAddress">
        <value value="127.0.0.1" typeConverter="IPAddressTypeConverter" />
      </param>
    </constructor>
  </register>
</root>
```

So in fact *both* the debugger *and* the final XML document are correct according to the rules of XML namespaces.

If you want to avoid having the serializer add `xmlns=""` then you need to make sure that the nodes you are inserting are created with the same namespace as the parent element to which they are being added.  Exactly how you achieve this depends on how you're creating the `XmlElement` objects.

Comment: To be honest I was unfamiliar with this particular rule.
Your solution worked. Thanks